# Probability of variable taking a certain value over a period of time based on historical data

Tags: probability, continuity

I have question for a real application problem at work, although it is ages since I took my probability courses back in Uni.

I have a very large silo that is loaded and unloaded at set intervals, typically the silo will be either empty, loading, unloading or loaded. The silo is usually left either empty or loaded for a few days. I have a lot of historical data of the silo's load vs time, so I was hopping to being able to estimate the probability of the silo being at a certain level for a certain period of time from the history of it.

I can easily integrate the level/time wave function/plot to obtain an average, or discretize the continuos into hourly intervals to form a distribution and from there obtain a probability of the silo being at any given level at a particular instant, but I don't know how to include the period function so that it is very unlikely that the silo will be partially full/empty for a long period.

Thanks!